# How to pass HTTP request parameters containing space and filter for ^word$

Tags: python, parameters, python-requests

I am making a REST API call, by passing param with space and filtering for specific a word with regex `^word$`.

```py
import requests

url ='http://xxxx/api/'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
word = "word contain space"
filter_data = f'^{word}$'
payload = {f'filter': filter_data}
request.get(url, params=params, auth=(xxxx, pwd), headers=headers)
```

Space problem will be solved if use

```py
import urllib

payload = {f'filter': filter_data}
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
```

however exact search `^` and `$` does not work. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Maybe that API doesn't support regex searches?  What does its documentation say?

Comment: can you add desired output for `filter_data` and `payload` parameters?

Comment: what's the purpose of `f'filter'` expression?

Comment: for JSON requests you should use `r = requests.post(url, json=payload ...`